# Get Latest Source Code in TFS without Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

Uses: Visual Studio 2013; TFS Express 2012;

For an Audit and BCP Requirement, Another member of an IT staff needs to get a copy of the latest version of the Source code in TFS for back-up purpose.

This authorized member of the IT Staff needs not be a developer and should not be able to change or compile the code, but his sole privilege will be to download the latest version of the Source Code from TFS without any version of Visual Studio.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can use the online version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose the Team Foundation **client** to support your tasks:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181304.aspx

In your case, you can use the "Team Web Access for TFS". Team Web Access provides you **read-only access** to Team Foundation Version Control. **You can view files and even download the latest versions of them**. You can also compare two files, view version history, as well as view annotation information about a file, showing who made what changes in the file. You also have the ability to find and view Shelveset information. **You cannot, however, check information into or out of Team Foundation Version Control**.

[image]

Info taken from here:

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/04/25/wctfs_team-web-access.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. It was really helpful. I figured out you can download a zipped file of all the code.

Answer (score 2):

In TFS 2012 and 2013 you can give them access to the web only and have them download a read only Zip...

[image]